# how to solve SVN Commit Issue: forbidden by server

Tags: java, svn, eclipse

When I tried to commit my code using Eclipse. I got the following error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: The operation is forbidden by the server
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Changing file 'D:\workspace\DataItem.java' is forbidden by the server
URL access forbidden for unknown reason
svn: Access to '/abc/!svn/ver/8211/trunk/01_Application/DataItem.java' forbidden
RA layer request failed
svn: Additional errors:
svn: CHECKOUT of '/abc/!svn/ver/8211/trunk/01_Application/DataItem.java': 403 Forbidden
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: What did you do to solve your problem?

Comment: i checkout new repository. Updated my SVN. Even tried to commit from File system. but yet problem is not solved. Even i do have all rights

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this question has to be asked on StackOverflow, not on ServerFault.

The error `403 Forbidden` indicates that you don't have enough permissions to write to the particular repository subtree. You can't solve the problem yourself and you should contact repository administrator or manager for assistance with this. The bottom line is *you don't have enough permissions to perform the operation*.

Comment: Thanks But I had all permissions .In comment i have  mentioned that.

Comment: Problem get resolved by cleaning "saved data" from svn application.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well.
Check your SVN server and verify that you have directly "read/write" permissions instead of "inherited"
Good luck